# UISplitViewController iOS8 PopToViewController programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using an UISplitViewController and Size Classes on my application.
I'm displaying Master & Detail controllers all the time on iPads (UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible)

I set up my storyboards following this great SplitViewController [tutorial](http://whoisryannystrom.com/2014/11/17/UISplitViewController-iOS-7/)

So I'm supporting iOS 7 and 8 on my app. Everything is working but for a small problem I'm experiencing on iPhones with iOS8: (this doesn't happen in the 6+ landscape of course)

I want to programmatically show the Master Controller from the Detail controller.
I'm able to do this with:

```
[self showViewController:[self parentController] sender:self]; //Parent Controller is Master Controller
```

But this causes the Master controller to be pushed in top of the Detail Controller causing the back button of the navigation bar to stop working.

If I use:

`[[self navigationController] popToViewController:[self parentController] animated:YES]; // This works on iPhones with iOS7`

The application crashes with: **'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to get popped view controller.'** (I also tried popToRoot... nothing happens.)

Debugging the code I found that SplitViewController.viewControllers returns only a NavigationController with the Detail controller inside, so the Master is not inside nor root of the Navigation Controller.

But if I press the back button of the Navigation Bar it makes the pop animation simulating the Master was root.

I'm assuming this is all related to iOS8 and the fact that for iPhone 6+ you can have both Master and Detail visible on Landscape mode so the OS no longer keep both of them inside a NavigationController.

But my question is how can I programmatically pop to Master controller from the Detail then?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I fixed this problem with the code below, but I would love to know if there is a better way to do this.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

                // iOS 8 and later only.
                if (self.splitViewController) {

                    // If it's not an iPhone 6+ landscape.
                    if (self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass != UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular) {
                        UINavigationController *nav = self.splitViewController.viewControllers[0];
                        nav.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.parentController, self, nil];
                        [[self navigationController] popToViewController:[self parentController] animated:YES];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    [[self navigationController] popToViewController:[self parentController] animated:YES];
                }
            }
```